# GridView with equal rows

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview with 2 rows and 3 columns. Want to make the rows streched equally across the screen without having the user screen to see any of the rows. The rows should be of equal height (preferrably, the height of the gridview / 3).

Currently using this adapter:

```
public class HomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private int h;

    public HomeAdapter(Context context, int height) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        h = height;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 6;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        FunctionHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new FunctionHolder();
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_flipper, parent, false);
            holder.flipper = (ViewFlipper) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flipper);

        } else {
            holder = (FunctionHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        View topView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.first_item, null);
        View bottomView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.second_item, null);

        changeView(bottomView, position);
        changeView(topView, position);

        holder.flipper.addView(topView, 0);
        holder.flipper.addView(bottomView, 1);

        startAnimation(holder.flipper, position);
        convertView.setMinimumHeight(h);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        return convertView;
    }
```

gridview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<GridView
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_bg"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/home_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></GridView>
```

Comment: I have posted answer , please check it .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public static int getScreenHeight(Context c) {
        if (screenHeight == 0) {
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            screenHeight = size.y;
        }

        return screenHeight;
    }
```

Then set `GridView` **item's** height dynamically depending on height of device

```
  v.getLayoutParams().height = getScreenHeight(context)/3;
```